# How can I align a bunch of verts into a circle at once?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

I've been going through the process of creating a turtle shell. I've got everything mostly where I want it, but now, my outer ring of verts are really messy.

My goal is to have the outer ring of verts be a perfect circle, but as you can see, they're kinda scattered around at different positions. I want to align these so they become circular in the Z/X axis, regardless of their Y depth.

Is there a simple way to accomplish this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Go to preferences and make sure you have an add on enabled called *"Loop Tools"*. Enable it if it is not checked:

[image: Loop1]

Select the outer ring of your mesh, right-click and select `LoopTools > Circle`:

[image: Loop2]

You can make further adjustments from the *Operator Panel* in the bottom left if necessary.